# TreeNode key issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using TreeView control in WinForm.

I am trying to use the following code, but getting "NullReferenceException".
I am following the syntax provided i.e. `tree.Nodes[key].Nodes.Add(key,text)`

I don't know whats wrong with the code.

Please have a look at the code i used -

```
tvTree.Nodes.Add("Subjects", "Subjects");
tvTree.Nodes["Subjects"].Nodes.Add("Physics", "Physics");

tvTree.Nodes["Physics"].Nodes.Add("PhysicsP1", "Paper1");
tvTree.Nodes["Physics"].Nodes.Add("PhysicsP2", "Paper2");
tvTree.Nodes["Physics"].Nodes.Add("PhysicsP3", "Paper3");
```

Thanks for sharing your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also you may achieve this with

```
        tvTree.Nodes.Add("Subjects", "Subjects");
        tvTree.Nodes["Subjects"].Nodes.Add("Physics", "Physics");

        var phyNode = tvTree.Nodes.Find("Physics", true).First();

        phyNode.Nodes.Add("PhysicsP1", "Paper1");
        phyNode.Nodes.Add("PhysicsP2", "Paper2");
        phyNode.Nodes.Add("PhysicsP3", "Paper3");
```

Comment: Thanks Emre! I got idea from you and Austin.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that the "Physics" nodes are not direct children of `tvTree` but instead are children of the "Subjects" node.  What should make this easier is that [TreeNodeCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esz34cwb.aspx) returns a TreeNode that you can reference later on.

```
var subjects = tvTree.Nodes.Add("Subjects", "Subjects");
var physics = subjects.Nodes.Add("Physics", "Physics");

physics.Nodes.Add("PhysicsP1", "Paper1");
physics.Nodes.Add("PhysicsP2", "Paper2");
physics.Nodes.Add("PhysicsP3", "Paper3");
```

If you only have the name, you can use [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find.aspx):

```
var parentName = "from wherever";

var parentNodes = tvTree.Nodes.Find(parentName, true);

/* handle multiple results */
/* add children */
```

Comment: Thanks Austin! The code is perfect if i know the child nodes. I am actually getting the nodes from database with their levels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
tvTree.Nodes["Subjects"].Nodes["Physics"].Add("PhysicsP1", "Paper1");
```